# Using BitMaps to get images from Instagram API

Tags: java, android, api, instagram

I have build an app. I use bitmaps to get images from Instagram API and stora them in a GridView.

But I've a problem, when I use bitmaps and memory cache.

My code is:

```
public void DisplayImage(String urrl, ImageView imageView) {
    String url =  urrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);

    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

    if (bitmap != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}
```

The variable `bitmap` returns null, from method `memoryCache.get(url)`:

```
 public Bitmap get(String id){
    try{
        if(!cache.containsKey(id)) {
            return null; }else {

        return cache.get(id); }
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried some solutions, but with no success.
I saw other solutions for similar problems, but neither can solve mine.

I'm new to bitmaps, and this kind of stuff.

**EDIT**

```
  public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache= Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));//Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private long size=0;//current allocated size
    private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

    public MemoryCache(){
        //use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit){
        limit=new_limit;
        Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        try{
            if(!cache.containsKey(id)) {
                return null; }else {
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78
            return cache.get(id); }
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        try{
            if(cache.containsKey(id))
                size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
        if(size>limit){
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if(size<=limit)
                    break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try{
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78
            cache.clear();
            size=0;
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap==null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

ImageLoader:

```
    public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Handler handler = new Handler();// handler to display images in UI thread

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.crayon;

    public void DisplayImage(String urrl, ImageView imageView) {
        String url =  urrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);

        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

**SOLUTION** 
In class MyGridView, i used Glide like Shmuel send on link!

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.medialist_inflate, null);
    imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);


    Glide.with(context).load(imageThumbList.get(position)).into(imgView);

    return view;
```

Comment: This looks like a good beginning, but its incomplete.  Its expected that memoryCache.get() will sometimes return null.  You're then supposed to request the URL from the network, and add the bitmap returned to the cache.  Does that code not exist, or is it failing?  Have you traced through it?

Comment: I will edit my code and put all files, complete for you can see. Thanks!

Comment: Well theres no reason for you to be writing the cache class at all.  Just use a LRUCache

Comment: i will try.. just a minute @GabeSechan

Comment: can put an example in a answer format?

Comment: Continue null... i don't know what to do more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loading images from a web url the best practice approach is the use the Glide image loading library.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

It is an open source image loading library that is recommend and supported by Google.

The api looks like this -

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .crossFade()
    .into(myImageView);
```

See how easy that is :D

It automatically handles caching the images (both in memory and to disk).

Comment: for exame, how this is possible -> `myImageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_image_view, container, false);` this give me a error because you are tying to cast a Layout in a ImageView, right?

Comment: works! after see better what you send, works finally! :) Thank you very much!